# How can we estimate weights given a set of data?(Neural networks back prop)

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

i'm trying to do a project to learn, i was asked to use the back-propagation algorithm. I was given a data set, 7 inputs 1 out-put, no initial weights were given. We are told to estimate the weights given the data, the data is all numbers, the 7 inputs given are numbers, how would i estimate the weights?

Answer (score 0):

Weights can be assigned for initial phase using a random number generator. After that your backpropagation should re adjust the weights based on the error difference between your output and target value.